# Behavior or Behaviour tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We need to decide on whether we are going to use [behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour) or [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior), then delete the unused one.

Being from the UK, I'd propose that we use [behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour), but as it seems that the audience is more american than british, it may make more sense to stick with [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) (plus that's currently being used the most).

What do you guys prefer?

Answer (score 4):

The SE sites I've been involved in tend to the American spelling of words for consistency and so make some of the British spellings synonyms of the American ones.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me. I know I am bad for using the alternative spelling, being Canadian, but I will try to change my ways. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Thank you, as agreed, the cheque is in the mail. (***I kid, I kid***)

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for the shorter spelling of [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) over [behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour).

Not only will this prevent every potential [behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour)-tagging user from having to tap the 'u' key, saving multiple seconds over the next decade, StackExchange will end up transmitting one fewer character every time it displays the word, saving quintillionths of dollars in hosting, processing and transmission fees.